# Flutter/Dart How to Save Network Image with SharedPreferences localy

Tags: flutter, image, dart, sharedpreferences, local

i want to load by first opening from the App with Internet Connection many Pictures and at the next opening i want to get my images from my local Storage.

Can anyone give me a easy example with a network image loaded with URL and save it with SharedPreferences localy?

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert it to string using `base64Encode` check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65361695/flutter-shared-preference-how-do-i-save-a-network-image-to-local-memory) thread

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this [full example](https://medium.com/@nikhil725051/just-four-simple-steps-to-save-images-to-local-storage-flutter-89c93d76ad0c)

or as suggested convert to base64 and store in local db. Depending how many images you want to save/load and use case.